# A conceptual question about waves

Tags: waves, string, wavelength

If the tension in a string with fixed ends is *slightly* increased then does the wavelength of a wave travelling along the string change, or does only the frequency change?

Comment: Please don't write your question in all caps.

Comment: Fixed caps. I do hope that wasn't the *only* reason for the downvotes, but I think it might have been.

Comment: You left out an important variable. $v=\nu{}\lambda{}$ Velocity ($v$) equals frequency ($\nu{}$) times wavelength ($\lambda{}$). You can't change any one of those three variables without changing at least one of the other two.

Comment: Are the ends of the string fixed (so that the wave is a standing wave) ? Or are the ends of the string free to move ?

Comment: My teacher told that If we increase the tension in the string the velocity increases , frequency increases but the wavelength remains constant if we increase the tension slightly.I am not able to understand the point that why does wavelength remains constant

Comment: @gandalf61 yes the ends are fixed

Comment: You might want to add in your question that you know that when you tighten the string on a musical instrument, the frequency increases because we can hear that.

Comment: It looks like @gandalf61 was right. All caps was the only reason for 6 down votes and 2 close votes. Now there are 3 up votes too.

Comment: Voting to reopen. Once the OP clarified that the string's ends are fixed (which I have added to the question) then the question is perfectly clear and has a straightforward answer.

Comment: @gandalf61 SO WHAT IF THE ONLY REASON FOR DOWNVOTES WAS THE ALL CAPS TYPESETTING. WRITING IN ALL CAPS SHOWS A COMPLETE LACK OF RESPECT FOR THE READER AND IT LOOKS LIKE THE QUESTIONER IS SHOUTING. LIKE HOW THIS COMMENT LOOKS LIKE IM SHOUTING BUT IM ACTUALLY NOT AND YOU CAN NEVER HOLD IT AGAINST ME SINCE YOU APPARENTLY DONT CARE WHETHER SOMETHING IS IN ALL CAPS OR NOT

Comment: @hft - Don't care isn't really right. It is less pleasant and harder to read. But too many questions are down voted and/or closed for reasons other than their physics content. Things like poor wording, or expressing a doubt that some established part of physics is right. I would like to see people be a little less quick on the draw.

Comment: @mmesser314 My point is that things other than the physics content do *matter*. Presentation matters. Presentation is part of communicating. If the question is not communicated clearly, then it is *not* clear.

Comment: I agree. But sometimes they should matter a little less.

Comment: @hft Your all caps comment above is ridiculous. Not writing in all caps is a *convention* - a good and useful convention, but one that not everyone in the world understands, especially if their first language is not English. I am sure that the OP did not mean to show any lack of respect. They made a simple mistake - and a mistake that can be quickly and easily corrected. In my opinion, downvoting a question just because it is in all caps is ignorant and lazy, just like downvoting just because of spelling or grammar errors is ignorant and lazy (although I am sure people do that too).

Comment: @gandalf61 As usual, I disagree.

Comment: @mmesser314 I agree, they should matter less, but it is hard for me to ignore.

Answer (score 3):

If the two ends of the string are fixed - so the wave is a standing wave -  then its wavelength is determined by the length of string, and this will not change if the tension in the string changes by a small amount. However, the velocity and the frequency of the wave *will* change (and in the same proportions).

Note that we are talking here about the wavelength of the wave *in the vibrating string*. The sound wave that the vibrating string causes in the surrounding air has the same frequency as the wave in the string but it has a different wavelength, because the speed of sound in air is different from the speed of vibrations in the string.

If we talk about the sound wave, then its frequency must match the frequency of the vibrating string. Since the frequency of the vibrating string changes, so does the frequency of the sound wave. So the wavelength of the *sound wave* also changes so as to keep its speed (in air) constant.

Comment: Can it happen that the mode of vibration changes ( say from first overtone to second overtone) and the frequency adjusts itself in such a way that their product becomes equal to velocity

Comment: @MadhavMittal This is the point of emphasising a *slight* change in tension. A slight change in tension will not change the mode of vibration if the string is already vibrating.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a long string, you grab it at a point and wiggle it with any frequency, $f$, you want. This creates a wave with that frequency that travels along the string. The frequency will be the frequency of your wiggles.

The period, $T$,of the wave is the time it takes for one complete wiggle.

$$T = 1/f$$

This is because if you make $f$ wiggles in a second, each wiggle must take $1/f$ seconds.

The speed, $v$, the wave travels is governed by the density of the string and the tension. If you increase the tension and repeat the experiment, the wave will travel faster.

The wavelength, $\lambda$, is the distance the wave travels in one wiggle time, $T$. It is the distance between crests of the wave. It is the distance a crest travels by the time the next crest is generated.

$$\lambda = vT$$

So $\lambda$ increases if tension increases, even if you keep $f$ and $T$ the same.

---

Your teacher is talking about a slightly different situation. Suppose you move a bow over a violin string or pluck it. The distance is fixed. You can tighten the string to increase tension.

The bow creates with a lot of waves with different frequencies. The all die away if you just let it vibrate.

But some waves have just the right frequency to get bigger as you bow. If the wavelength is twice the length of the string, a crest will will up the string and back just in time for the next crest to be generated. Generating the new crest pushes the string in the same direction the old crest moves it. So the motion gets bigger.

So waves in a violin string have a wavelength of twice the string length. Or $1/2$ or $1/3$ that wavelength. They have frequencies that correspond to those wavelengths.

If you tighten the string, waves have the same wavelength. But they travel faster. A higher frequency makes the round trip just in time to be amplified.

For a violin, $\lambda$ is fixed. The $f$ that matches that $\lambda$ increases. $f$ goes up.