# Frequency of light wave doesn't change with media

Tags: optics, waves

I have been trying to derive snell's law in the case of a monochromatic harmonic plane wave at a planar interface. By the same derivation I also wanted to derive how the frequency of the wave does not change at the interface. Here's the context:

[image]

We solve the planar wave helmholtz equation in both regions and get phasors:

in region n1: $U_1 = A_1 e^{-j \vec{k_1} \cdot\vec{r}}$, with $\vec{k_1}=(k_{1x}, 0, k_{1z})^T$ such that $k_1 = |\vec{k_1}| =\omega_1/c_1=n_1\omega_1/c_0$

in region n2: $U_2 = A_2 e^{-j \vec{k_2} \cdot\vec{r}}$, with $\vec{k_2}=(k_{2x}, 0, k_{2z})^T$ such that $k_1 = |\vec{k_2}| =\omega_2/c_2=n_2\omega_2/c_0$

Upon applying the boundary condition at the interface:

$\forall \vec{r_0}=(x_0,y_0,0)^T: U_1(\vec{r_0})=U_2(\vec{r_0})$

i.e. $\vec{k_1} \cdot\vec{r_0}=\vec{k_2} \cdot\vec{r_0}$ which finally yields (knowing $\vec{k_{1,2}}=(sin(\theta_{1,2})k_{1,2},0,cos(\theta_{1,2})k_{1,2})^T$):

$n_1w_1sin(\theta_1)=n_2w_2sin(\theta_2)$

At this point I am a little lost on how to proceed with the frequencies. I of course know that w1 = w2, but I hoped for a way to derive it with the phase matching boundary condition here...
If any such trick exists I'd appreciate some help.

Comment: The frequency is always determined by the device that is generating the wave, not by the medium that the wave is traveling through.

Comment: This question is not about the same situation, but it might help - [A conceptual question about waves](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/796760/37364)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's simplify to one dimension with a $+x$ propagating wave, boundary at $x=0$.

The left wave is:

$$\psi_L(0, t) = A_L e^{i(kx-\omega_L t)}=A_L\exp(-i\omega_L t) $$

On the right:

$$\psi_R(0, t) = A_R\exp(-i\omega_R t) $$

Based on the appropriate physics continuity across the boundary, they are proportional:

$$ \psi_L(0,t) = \alpha\psi_R(0, t) $$

where the ratio is:

$$ \alpha = \frac{\psi_L(0,t)}{\psi_R(0, t)}$$

$$ \alpha = \frac{
A_Le^{(-i\omega_L t)}
}
{
A_Re^{(-i\omega_R t)}}
$$

$$\alpha = \frac{A_L}{A_R}
e^{i(\omega_R - \omega_L)}t
=  \frac{A_L}{A_R}e^{i\Delta\phi(t)t}$$

where $\Delta\phi$ is the phase difference at the boundary.

(Note: I went the extra step to $\phi$ not to have a gratuitous step; rather, it's because thinking about the phase as a scalar field, and I mean geometric scalar, not "just a number", over space and time can really clarify understanding of wave-phenomenon).

1. I'm rescaling alpha to absorb the amplitudes--too much MathJax

But it's still constant:

$$ \dot{\alpha} = \frac{d\Delta\phi}{dt}
e^{i\Delta\phi(t)t}=0
$$

Which only works if the phase difference derivative is zero:

$$ \frac{d\Delta\phi}{dt} =
\big[\frac{d}{dt}\big](\omega_R - \omega_L)t = \omega_R - \omega_L = 0
$$

or:

$$\omega_R = \omega_L $$

Now I noticed I assumed the amplitude ratio is constant--so that is a problem. There're two solution I leave as an exercise:

1. rewrite the thing as a general wave expanded over its Fourier expansion and get the same result.
2. think about phase as a relation between $\omega$ and $k$, and why $\omega/k$ is the phase velocity, while $d\omega/dk$ is velocity of the amplitude modulation envelope, aka the group velocity.